# Failed to establish a new connection error using Python requests Errno -2 Name or service unknown

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to make a request to an API with Python. I am able to make the request with curl without issue but I have something wrong with my Python request.

Why does this code,

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

emailadd = 'user123@example.com'
domain = 'example.com'

spantoken = 'omitted'

def checkUserLicensed(useremail):
     url = ('https://api.spannigbackup.com/v1/users/' + useremail)
     print(url)
     response = requests.get(url, auth=(domain,spantoken))
     print(response)

checkUserLicensed(emailadd)
```

Return this error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.spannigbackup.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/users/user123@example.com 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f73ca323748>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```